# Locations in HTTP Requests

Tags: android, location, httprequest, google-places-api

I was wondering how locations work in a HTTP request. I actually want my location that im currently in to be part of the request but im not sure how to do this.

I store the current location in a LatLng object; would I need to extract the lat and long from this and put it into the request, if so how? or is there a way to just include the LatLng object as a whole in the request? the example I want to implement this into is below

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?rankby=distance&location=************,***********&types=meal_takeaway&sensor=true&key=API_KEY
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking what I think you are, how to insert your coordinates into the URL, then there are a few ways you can do it.

The easiest would be something like this, assuming `coords` is the name of your LatLng variable and `getLat()` and `getLng()` are the methods of it that returns the coordinates:

```
String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?rankby=distance&types=meal_takeaway&sensor=true&key=API_KEY&location=" + coords.getLat() + "," + coords.getLng();
```

There you're simply inserting the parameters. If you want to do something cooler, you could override your LatLng object's toString() method to return the coordinates in the proper format. E.g.

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return getLat() + "," + getLng();
}
```

Doing that would allow us to change the initial url to something along the lines of:

```
String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?rankby=distance&types=meal_takeaway&sensor=true&key=API_KEY&location=" + coords.toString();
```

Why do that? There are a number of reasons: it's slightly cleaner, a tiny bit more OO-based, and I like how that looks in comparison.

As for inserting the API Key, which you probably have saved in your String resources, you would do something very similar:

```
String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?rankby=distance&types=meal_takeaway&sensor=true&key=" + context.getResources().getString(R.string.your_api_key) + "&location=" + coords.toString();
```

Clearly for that you need some kind of Context to get the resource there, but that should be available. Just showing you some different ways.